# Change output spatial reference for ArcGISTiledMapService

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the New Zealand Topo50 maps for my basemaps from an ArcGIS map server at http://services.arcgisonline.co.nz/ArcGIS/rest/services/LINZ/geotiffs/MapServer. However, this service has a spatial reference of `EPSG:2193` and the tiles are being projected over Europe instead of New Zealand.

I've noticed that vector feature layers, e.g. `FeatureLayer` and `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`, automatically add an output spatial reference to the request so that the returned features are in `EPSG:3857` (Web Mercator). Raster layers don't seem to work the same though.

What can I do to have the basemap projected correctly?

My code:

```
var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo"
});

var topo50Layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
  "http://services.arcgisonline.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/LINZ/geotiffs/MapServer"
);

map.addLayer(topo50Layer);
```

Comment: As usual, discovered the answer five minutes after posting this question, having spent three hours trying to figure it out. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` is only useful when the service is in the same spatial reference as the map. This is because it uses the [Map Tile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000pt000000) resources of the REST API which cannot request re-projected images.

`ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` uses the [Export Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Export_Map/02r3000000v7000000/) operation which *does* have the capability to re-project images, although this will be slower.

Changing to `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` will request the images in the map's spatial reference.

Comment: this is not totally correct.  ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer is useful to use with non-mercator map services in applications that leverage the same projection.  http://jsfiddle.net/mca5xqdw/

Comment: You are absolutely correct, @JohnGravois. I've edited my answer to be more general.

Comment: tristanm++ :)  .

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to specify the SpatialReference when creating the map using the extent [option](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1). The dynamic map service layer should automatically project onto the map's spatial reference. It would look something like this

```
var map = new Map("map", {
  extent: new Extent({
    xmin: <xmin value>,
    ymin: <ymin value>,
    xmax: <xmax value>,
    ymax: <ymax value>,
    spatialReference:{ wkid: 2193 }
  })
});
```

A [working sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_customextent_and_sr.html) of this is provided on the documentation page.
For more information on how to create an Extent, take a look at the API documentation for [extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html).

Comment: @tristanm Oops didn't see that you'd posted the answer to your own question. I hope this helps someone else having a similar question but who doesn't have access to map documents on the server and wants to perform this operation on the client side using JavaScript only.

Comment: Thanks @ashima that's a great answer too for a lot of cases.

Comment: Manually setting the map's initial extent to 2193 doesn't work, possibly due to a bug ("Map: Geometry (wkid: 2193) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: 102100) init.js:1256"). Other WKIDs do work, though.

Comment: this is not a bug, both individual coordinate tags like "xmin" and "xmax" along with "wkid" need to be wrapped in quotes to make them valid JSON objects.